# Disable Shutdown Event Tracker from Command Line

Tags: windows, shutdown

How can I disable the windows shutdown event tracker from the command line? I've seen that I can disable it by editing the registry, but I am hoping there is another way.

Thank you!

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to disable it across a number of windows servers using puppet as it conflicts with tests being run on the machines. If a machine restarts for some reason it causes all tests on that machine to hang until someone notices and manually goes in and tells it to continue.

Comment: You should really be doing this via group policy.

Comment: When you say "editing the registry" do you mean *manually*? The [`reg`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643.aspx) tool can automate the required changes.

Comment: No I just mean editing it at all. I don't want to touch the registry myself if I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your registry change as a .reg text file and execute it from the command prompt.

From [MS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd379001(v=ws.10).aspx):

Requirements
Credentials: Administrators

Tools: Regedit.exe

To export a registry setting to a .reg file
Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
In the console tree, navigate to the registry entry that you want to include in the file.

Add or modify the entry that you want to export to the .reg file.

With the entry selected, on the File menu, click Export.

In the Save in box, navigate to the location for the .reg file.
In the File name box, type a name for the .reg file.
Under Export range, click Selected branch, and then click Save.

Comment: So there is no way around manually editing the registry?

Comment: well, you can use group policy, but that probably is doing a registry change as well.